# Disable page interactions (eg links, inputs) when off canvas menu is open?

Tags: jquery

I have an off canvas menu. When you open the menu a small amount of the normal page content is still visible. When you click or tap on this area the menu closes.

This is working when the normal content is text and images. However when its a link then the link gets followed, if its an input then the input becomes active.

How can I disable links, inputs, etc when the menu is open? Can I do this with JavaScript (I'm using jQuery)?

The JavaScript is very simple. I just toggle a class when you click or tap the menu and then animate the page with CSS.

```
  $('.off-canvas-menu-trigger').click(function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('off-canvas-menu-is-open');
  });

  $('.page-content').click(function() {
    $('body').removeClass('off-canvas-menu-is-open');
  });
```

Comment: possibly this: [e.stopPropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not JavaScript but the best solution is to use CSS to disable an entire div and its contense from being clickable:

```
pointer-events: none
```